# Parse XML data and append a new element using XML::Simple

Tags: xml, perl, xml-simple

I'm using [`XML::Simple`](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::Simple) and [`XML::Dumper`](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::Dumper). I'm well aware of the issues surrounding the former module. If I could use an alternative library, I would.

What I want to achieve is to load the XML, then append lines to it. This is my XML structure before the script has run.

```
<person>
  <appearance>
     <param name="height" value="6,3"/>
  </appearence>
</person>
```

The script, or what I intended to code, should load this XML from a file, then append a `<param>` element onto `<appearence>`. I've attempted it using this code:

```
use warnings;

use XML::Simple;
use XML::Dumper;

my $xml = XMLin('xml_import.xml');

$xml->{appearence} .= qq{<param name="age" value="22" />};
my $new_xml = XMLout($xml, noattr => 1, NoEscape => 1);

open(FILE, ">xml_import.xml");
print FILE $new_xml;
close FILE;
```

Unfortunately the output is this:

```
<opt>
  <appearence>HASH(0x1722190)<param name="age" value="22" /></appearence>
</opt>
```

Not only do I lose my original `<person>` tags to `<opt>` but that `HASH` string replaces what I assume what was the existing `<param>` element. I've read over the documentation for `XML::Simple` but I cannot spot what argument should be used to prevent this from happening.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why better XML modules could be unavailable to you, unless someone is holding your family hostage. Would you like to explain the problem?

Comment: Not particularly. There are many reasons why alternative libraries are unavailable in this issue. Since when was stackoverflow a site for interrogation?

Comment: Note: While XML::Simple is quite bad for parsing XML, it's positively awful for writing XML. It will generate XML that's different from the XML you read in. Avoid this deprecated module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of using [XML::Simple](http://p3rl.org/XML::Simple) is to use Perl data structures, not XML in your code.

Your problems show exactly why the module is discouraged. You have to use `ForceArray` to be able to easily change the number of the elements in a parent, and you have to clear `KeyAttr` to block a special handling of the `name` attribute.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::Simple;

my $xml = << '__XML__';
<person>
  <appearance>
     <param name="height" value="6,3"/>
  </appearance>
</person>
__XML__

my $simple = XMLin($xml, ForceArray => 1,
                         KeepRoot   => 1,
                         KeyAttr    => [],
                  );

push @{ $simple->{person}[0]{appearance}[0]{param} }, { name  => 'age',
                                                        value => 22,
                                                      };
print XMLout($simple, KeepRoot => 1);
```

For comparison, the same task in [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
open file.xml ;
my $p := insert element param append /person/appearance ;
set $p/@name 'age' ;
set $p/@value 22 ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: That's really the worst bit of XML::Simple - most of the requests we see are _insanely easy_ with the various options available from the other parsers.

Answer (score 0):

1.The reason you lose  tags is "XMLin() normally discards the root element name. Setting the 'KeepRoot' option to '1' will cause the root element name to be retained."

2.After reading xml from file, should operate the variable as perl data structure.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use XML::Simple qw(:strict);
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml = XMLin('xml_import.xml', KeepRoot => 1, KeyAttr => ["param"], ForceArray => ["param"]);
print '-----$xml-----', "\n", Dumper($xml), "\n";

my $new_node = {'name' => 'age', 'value' => '22'};
push $xml->{person}->{appearance}->{param}, $new_node;
print '-----Insert a new node to $xml-----', "\n", Dumper($xml), "\n";

my $new_xml = XMLout($xml, NoAttr => 1, NoEscape => 1, KeepRoot => 1, KeyAttr => []);
print '-----$new_xml-----', "\n", $new_xml, "\n";
```

Or

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use XML::Simple qw(:strict);
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml = XMLin('xml_import.xml', KeepRoot => 1, KeyAttr => {param => "+name"}, ForceArray => ["param"]);
print '-----$xml-----', "\n", Dumper($xml), "\n";

my $new_node = {'name' => 'age', 'value' => '22'};
$xml->{person}->{appearance}->{param}->{age} = $new_node;
print '-----Insert a new node to $xml-----', "\n", Dumper($xml), "\n";

my $new_xml = XMLout($xml, NoAttr => 1, NoEscape => 1, KeepRoot => 1, KeyAttr => {param => "+name"});
print '-----$new_xml-----', "\n", $new_xml, "\n";
```